# shared_examplesはrspec3.0から使えない？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

rspec2.99でinclude_examplesを使用しています。
spechoge.rb

```
describe 'hoge_type' do
  before do
  end
  include_examples 'toarutesuto'
end
```

spec/support/lib/kyouyuu.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "テストを共有" do
  before do
  end
  shared_examples 'toarutesuto' do
    before do
    end
    it'' do
    end
```

テストを実行すると、以下ワーニングが出ます。

```
Deprecation Warnings:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               Accessing shared_examples defined across contexts is deprecated.
               Please declare shared_examples within a shared context, or at the top level.
               This message was generated at: /poge/hoge/workspace/transpec/spechoge.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[説明を](http://rspec.info/blog/2013/07/rspec-2-14-is-released/)読んでみたのですが、shared_examplesは3.0からは使えなくなって直接spechoge.rb等に書かなければならないということでしょうか？
すみません、英語がきちんと理解できていなくて

shared_examples⇒shared_examples_for
include_examples⇒it_behaves_like
に書き直しても同じワーニングが出ます。

回答をいただいた通りdescribeを⇒shared_contextに書き換えてみました。そうすると以下のようなエラーが出ました。rspecのバージョンを上げる必要があるのでしょうか？

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:266:in `find_and_eval_shared': Could not find shared examples "toarutesuto" (ArgumentError)
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:185:in `block in it_behaves_like'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `module_eval'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `subclass'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:342:in `describe'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:184:in `it_behaves_like'
        from /poge/hoge/workspace/transpec4.0/spec/lib/cloudstack/os_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `module_eval'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `subclass'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:342:in `describe'
        from /poge/hoge/workspace/transpec4.0/spec/lib/cloudstack/os_spec.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `module_eval'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:369:in `subclass'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:342:in `describe'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
        from /poge/hoge/workspace/transpec4.0/spec/lib/cloudstack/os_spec.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `each'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `rescue in run'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `run'
        from /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

警告を訳すと以下のようになります。

> contextをまたがってshared_examplesにアクセスするのは非推奨になりました。
>   shared_contextの中、もしくはトップレベルにshared_examplesを定義してください。

「contextをまたがる」というのは「describeをまたがる」と読み替えた方がわかりやすいかもしれません。
（そのままだと同じdescribeブロック内でしかshared_examplesが使い回せない、ということです）

「shared_contextの中、もしくはトップレベルにshared_examplesを定義してください」とあるのでそれが解決策になります。
この場合、kyouyuu.rbが別ファイルになっているので、shared_contextを使うのが良さそうです。

```
# spec/support/lib/kyouyuu.rb
require 'spec_helper'

shared_context "テストを共有" do
  before do
  end
  shared_examples 'toarutesuto' do
    before do
    end
    it'' do
    end

# spechoge.rb
describe 'hoge_type' do
  include_context 'テストを共有'
  before do
  end
  it_behaves_like 'toarutesuto'
end
```

このようにshared_context内にshared_examplesを定義して、必要なテストでinclude_contextすればshared_examplesが別のファイルでも使えるようになります。

Comment: 「describeをまたがる」なるほど、そういう意味だったのですね。書き換えてみたところrspec-coreでエラーが出るようになりました。rspecのバージョンを上げる必要があるということでしょうか？

Comment: spechoge.rbに`include_context 'テストを共有'`が追加されていないのでは？と思います。確認してみてください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りinclude_contextが抜けていました。追加したら解決しました。